# Facebook Bot Getting started button

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Only administrator of the app can see Getting started button , So I am the admin of the app and I can see the Getting started button
[image]

Do I need to submit my app for review by facebook for "pages_messaging" permission so any logged in user can see the "Get started button"?

Comment: Of course you do …

Comment: I did submitted the app for review but my app donot give any auto response unless get started button is clicked , but the facebook app process needs me to provide some AUTOMATED REPLIES https://i.imgur.com/dBOX0TI.png which my app doesnt have it only have questions with buttons user can click on

Comment: Well then chose the other option, and describe how to test your bot in the detailed review instructions?

Comment: There are 2 options one for automatic bots and other for live messaging mine is using bots but user can only use buttons to send/recieve next steps/replies from the code

Comment: I still cannot get the "Get Started" button to work for non-admins